# Passing variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

The variable $q=$_GET["q"]; is passing correctly the value "q" to the $query and echoing the $row['YEAR'].

HOWEVER, it is not working with the while statement IN THE SAME CODE.

```
while ($rows = $result2->fetch_array())

{
$row0 [] = $rows['YEAR'];            
$row1 [] = $rows['MONTH'];        
$row2 [] = $rows['SALES'];
}
```

IF I try to type directly the value after the $_GET it does work ( $q=2013;   for example )

Can anyone give me a help to make the while work with $q=$_GET["q"];

Bellow is the complete code.

Appreciate any help

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','pswd','database');


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit(); 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE `YEAR`='".$q."'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($row = $result->fetch_array())

{
echo "<td>" . $row['YEAR'] . "</td>";

}   

$result2 = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($rows = $result2->fetch_array())

{
$row0 [] = $rows['YEAR'];           
$row1 [] = $rows['MONTH'];      
 $row2 [] = $rows['SALES'];
 }  



/* free result set */
$result->close();


 $mysqli->close();

 ?>
```

Comment: ___warning___ using mysqli isnt mean you are safe from sql injection your code is vulnerable to sql injection .. you need to properly escape request ... so  either use mysqli_real_escape_string or better prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

`$q=$_GET["q"];` will return null if you don't have submit a form with `method='get'` or the URL of you page does not contain a query string with `?q=2013` like `www.example.com?q=2013`.

Comment: I am using a selector box and AJAX to send the value to $q=$_GET["q"]; however it is not working for the while statement. I f I type the value directly, for example $q=$_GET["q"]; instead I do $q=2013; it does work.